# Unable to capture request and response using Fiddler, I want to develop a new tool

Tags: .net, fiddler

I have an application, where the fiddler is unable to capture request and response xml. Application is based in .net, Web based https:// . How do i develop some tool which captures request and response and the URL that is called. i need only these 3 things in the tool .Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** How do I rebuild Fiddler?
**A:** Write tens of thousands of lines of code.

**Q:** How do I use Fiddler to capture my traffic? 
**A:** That's a much better question. See http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp

**Q:** I don't want to use Fiddler for some reason.
**A:** Configure System.NET Tracing.